# Highcharts: Dynamically size a solid gauge chart

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I would like a solid gauge chart that adequately fills it's container. The only way to do this is to give it a size of over 100%.

```
    pane: {
        center: ['50%', '85%'],
        size: '140%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    },
```

I also want the containing div to be vertically resizable, the problem being that, when it is resized, the chart eventually resizes outside of it's parent div's boundaries.

```
$('#resizer').resizable({

    handles: {'s': '#sgrip'},
    resize: function() {
        var chart = $('#container-speed').highcharts();
        chart.setSize(
            this.offsetWidth - 20, 
            this.offsetHeight - 20,
            false
        ); 
    }
});
```

Is there any way around this?

See example:
http://jsfiddle.net/swj1naq2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by deciding on a maximum allowed width and preventing the chart from further resizing when this maximum is breached (using the only changing variable which is height).

```
$('#resizer').resizable({

    handles: {'s': '#sgrip'},
    resize: function() {
        var chart = $('#container-speed').highcharts();
        // Get approx 70% of container width
        var maxAllowedWidth = (this.offsetWidth * 0.7)
        var containerHeight =  $(chart.container).height();

        // Max allowed width should be about 70% of containers 
        // height so keeping within this boundary will prevent spill
        if(containerHeight >= maxAllowedWidth && this.offsetHeight - 20 > containerHeight){
            return;
        }  
        chart.setSize(
            this.offsetWidth - 20, 
            this.offsetHeight - 20,
            false
        ); 
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dzudn5jq/3/